# Cannot get scripts to run in PowerShell

Tags: 2010, powershell, server, 2012

We installed SharePoint 2010 on Server 2012.

I am trying to install FBA, but cannot get the deploy script to run.

First I switch to PowerShell 2.0 doing the following:

```
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    PS C:\Users\sp_farm> powershell.exe -version 2
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    PS C:\Users\sp_farm> $psversiontable

    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8000
    BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.18606
    PSVersion                      2.0
    WSManStackVersion              2.0
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


    PS C:\Users\sp_farm> [Environment]::Version

    Major  Minor  Build  Revision
    -----  -----  -----  --------
    2      0      50727  8000
```

Then navigate to the installation directory:

```
    PS C:\Users\sp_farm> cd\
    PS C:\> cd '.\install files'
    PS C:\install files> cd .\2010FBAPack
```

Allow Scripts to Deploy:

```
    PS C:\install files\2010FBAPack> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Deploy FBA Script

```
    PS C:\install files\2010FBAPack> .\deploy
    The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.
    Get-SPSolution : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.34014 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.
    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\UnDeploy.ps1:40 char:18
    + $featureExists = Get-SPSolution $solutionName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    +                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData:         (Microsoft.Share...dletGetSolution:SPCmdletGetSolution) [Get-SPSolution], PlatformNotSupportedException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSolution

    Solution not installed
    restart-service : Service 'SharePoint 2010 Timer (SPTimerV4)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open
    SPTimerV4 service on computer '.'.
    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Deploy.ps1:58 char:16 restart-service <<<<  SPTimerV4 + CategoryInfo : CloseError:(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand

    Going to add solution
    Add-SPSolution : Access denied.
    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Deploy.ps1:63 char:15
    + Add-SPSolution <<<<  $solutionPath+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData:(Microsoft.Share...dletAddSolution:SPCmdletAddSolution) [Add-SPSolution], SecurityException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletAddSolution

    Going to install solution to all web applications
    Install-SPSolution : This solution contains resources scoped for a Web application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications.

    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Deploy.ps1:66 char:19
    + Install-SPSolution <<<<  –identity $solutionName –allwebapplications–GACDeployment + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...InstallSolution:SPCmdletInstallSolution) [Install-SPSolution], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallSolution

    Waiting for job to finish
    Timer job not found
    The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.
    restart-service : Service 'SharePoint 2010 Timer (SPTimerV4)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open SPTimerV4 service on computer '.'.
    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Activate.ps1:21 char:1
    + restart-service SPTimerV4
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + 
    CategoryInfo   : CloseError:(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand

    Deactivating/activating active features to ensure activation script is run Get-SPFeature : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.34014 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime. At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Activate.ps1:3 char:13
    +     $feature = Get-SPFeature $featureName
    +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletGetFeature:SPCmdletGetFeature) [Get-SPFeature], PlatformNotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetFeature

    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    At C:\install files\2010FBAPack\Activate.ps1:4 char:2
    +     $features =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService. ...
    +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

    PS C:\install files\2010FBAPack> '
    >>
```

I checked Shell access permissions and think everything is setup correctly.

Now I am at a loss of what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this workaround helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to simply enter the commands in PowerShell line by line instead of using the script provided with the FBA Pack. I don't know why the script wasn't running, but I can install without using the script.

Indeed you need to be in version 2.0, but with the last version of SharePoint Server 2010 which has to be used with slipstream when running SharePoint 2010 on Server 2012 already has the SharePoint PowerShell pointing at version 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known compatibility issue with SharePoint 2010 and Windows Management Framework 4.0 (WMF), which also includes PowerShell 3.0. If you install these components on a server that also runs SharePoint 2010, you may encounter errors when running SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets.

Please check below article for resolution of your issue.

**WORKAROUND Mentioned on MSDN**

To work around this issue, change the Target field value for SharePoint 2010 Management Shell. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then right-click SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.
2. Click Properties.
3. Click the Shortcut tab in the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell Properties window.
4. Input the following value in the Target field:

**Command**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Version 2.0 -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

[SharePoint 2010 PowerShell incompatibility with .NET 4.X](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/alexsearch/2013/12/11/sharepoint-2010-powershell-incompatibility-with-net-4-x/)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that. I also tried to edit the config file for powershell in that directory, but it kept changing it back to 4.0. If you look at the script I used powershell.exe -version 2 to switch to version 2 and confirmed using $psversiontable. So this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please check here...https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2012/09/05/sharepoint-2010-management-shell-net-4-0-runtime-version-error/

Comment: @Brian Is that working for you?